# Divisibility problem ($p \leq \sqrt{n}$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-factorization

> If $n \geq 2$ and $n$ is composite, then there exists a prime $p$ such that that $p \mid n$ and $p \leq \sqrt{n}$

As $n$ is composite, it follows that $n = ab$ for some $a, b \in \Bbb N$, where $1 < a < n$ and $1 < b < n$.

If $n$ was $6$, I can see how it would follow: $2|6$ and $2 \leq \sqrt{6}$.

I'm just unsure on how to prove this...

Comment: (The previous edit changed the sense of the inequality - I've swapped that back to what it should be.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose $a > \sqrt{n}$ and $b > \sqrt{n}$. What can you say about $ab$?

Comment: Is it, a² ≤ ab?

Comment: No. I don't see how you got that actually. Using the inequalities for $a$ and $b$, you should be able to get an inequality for $ab$.

Comment: I found a proof that stated, if n > 1 is composite then there exists p ≤ √n and p|n. It went on to say, n = p1p2 ... pk with 1 < p1 ≤ p2 ≤ ... ≤ pk and k ≥ 2. Therfore, p1² ≤ p1p2 ≤ n and p1|n so, p1 ≤ √n.

Comment: In that proof, $p_1^2 \leq p_1p_2$, that follows from the fact that $p_1 \leq p_2$ but here we don't know which of $a$ and $b$ is bigger, but that's OK because we don't need to know. On one hand we have $n = ab$, but by applying the inequalities $a > \sqrt{n}$ and $b > \sqrt{n}$ we see that $ab$ is greater than what?

Comment: Alright, apologies for my ignorance; I've yet to really grasp this topic. I'm unsure how you've conjured this inequality, but I'm going to say that ab is greater than √n ...?

Comment: While $ab > \sqrt{n}$, you can do better. As $b > \sqrt{n}$, $ab > a\sqrt{n}$. Agreed? If so, can you see what $a\sqrt{n}$ is greater than?